# MySQL: Putting condition in SELECT query based on column value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `user_profiles` and `user_friends`.

`user_profiles` has columns `id`, `user_privacy` and few other columns (like `username`, `age` etc).

`user_friends` has columns `user_id` and `friends_id`. One `user_id` can have multiple `friend_id`s

This query simply returns profile of user having id, say, 1997:

`select * from user_profiles 
    where prfls.id=1997;`

And this query returns profile of user having id 1997 only when it has got friend having id, say, 2001:

`select * from user_profiles prfls 
    inner join user_friends frnds on (prfls.id=frnds.user_id) 
    where prfls.id=1997 and frnds.friends_id=2001;`

However, I want to write a *single query* that will check if column `user_privacy` (in `user_profiles`) for user 1997 is false then the query shouldn't check for `friends_id` in `user_friends`. It should simply return profile of user 1997. But if the `user_privacy` is true then only it should check for it.

How can this query be written? (Preferably using joins and without using sub-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join for it:

```
select distinct t1.* from user_profiles t1
 left join user_friends t2 on(t1.id = t2.user_id)
 where t1.id = 1997 and 
  (user_privacy='false' or t2.friends_id = 2001)
```

Comment: This works perfect. Only thing is we need to say `select distinct t1.*` otherwise it returns redundant rows (especially when privacy is set false)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
select t1.*
from user_profiles t1
where t1.id = 1997
and (
     t1.user_privacy = 'false'
     or exists (select 1 from user_friends t2 where t1.id = t2.user_id and t2.friends_id = 2001)
    )
```

Without subquery, you can try this;)

```
select distinct t1.*
from user_profiles t1
inner join user_friends t2
on t1.id = 1997 and (t1.user_privacy = 'false' or (t1.id = t2.user_id and t2.friends_id = 2001))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
    FROM user_profiles P
    LEFT JOIN user_friends F ON F.user_id = P.id
        AND P.user_privacy = true
        AND F.friends_id = 2001
    WHERE P.id = 1997
```

1. Use `LEFT JOIN` so even if `user_privacy` is false, the query will still return the `user_profiles`
2. Add condition in the `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN` indicating that it will return the `user_friends` if `user_privacy` is true.
3. Move the filtering of `F.friends_id` in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`. (Thanks to @Msf vtp for verifying, cheers!)

Comment: When F.friends_id according left join is null then "F.friends_id = 2001" is false so the answer is not correct.

Comment: @Msfvtp If `F.friends_id` is null, then either `P.user_privacy == false` or `user_friends` table is empty

Comment: I know. Assume P.id=1997 and its user_privacy=false then your where clause is false (because "F.friends_id = 2001" will return false) and this row will not be in the result.

Comment: I believe the row from `users_profiles` will still be there. Please verify your assumption and share us your results. You can use sqlFiddle if you want.

Comment: I created sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e91a0/1 and compared there my answer and your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Msfvtp. OP please check his link and answer.

Comment: Haha @Msfvtp, okay let's make it correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I had quickly chosen this answer over other two because `OR` in where clause makes it tough to optimise query, hence cause performance penalty.

Comment: Sure @Atul. I updated my answer, you can check again if you want :)

Comment: @KaeL: Still nope. This fetches user profile for any random friends_id even after privacy set true